# iOS: Can my iPhone app access trusted CA certificates of the iPhone device / device's trust store?

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl

My iPhone application wants to access the iphone's CA trust store to validate the server certificate for TLS connection. Is it possible to access device key chain / trust store where all known trusted CA certificates stored ?

Thanks,
bms

=================================

Thanks for your reply. Let me give details about my set up. I have created a server certificate using openssl which I have installed at my tomcat server for https connections. Also, I have signed this server certificate using my Own CA and installed this CA/Root certificate into my iPhone though Safari(http url). Now, in my app, I would like validate the server cerificate(offered by tomcat) against the CA certificate installed in the profiles of iPhone device.

Is this kind of server validation possible in iOS(programmatically) ?.

If server certificate is signed by public CAs, then, secTrustEvaluate returns successful return code. But, for custom CA signed certificates, it returns "kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure".

Thanks,
bms

Comment: m able to solve the problem. We can validate the Custom CA signed server certificate provided Custom CA certificate should be trusted and installed into device key chain(either through email or Safari)

Comment: @bms did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Karthik, Yes. I have installed the my own CA certifictae into device key chain and used SecTrustEvaluate API for validation.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not specific enough. There is a really useful example to access the keychain to store certificates:

https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-Certificate--Key--and-Trust-Sample-Project

I think you have to add your certificate (in cer format) usong the following function:

```
SecCertificateRef certificate =  SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (CFDataRef) certificateData);
```

And if it was sucessfull, you can set it as root certificate for your networking module...

If you would like to evaluate it:

```
        CFArrayRef rootCerts = (CFArrayRef)[client.additionalRootCertificates allObjects];
        SecTrustResultType result;
        OSStatus returnCode;

        if (rootCerts && CFArrayGetCount(rootCerts)) {
            // this could fail, but the trust evaluation will proceed (it's likely to fail, of course)
            SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, rootCerts);
        }

        returnCode = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &result);

        if (returnCode == errSecSuccess) {
            proceed = (result == kSecTrustResultProceed || result == kSecTrustResultConfirm || result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified);
            if (result == kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure) {
                // TODO: should try to recover here
                // call SecTrustGetCssmResult() for more information about the failure
            }
        }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added details to my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you ingaham. It is one of the ways to do server validation against custom CA certificate. But, I don't want to bundle my CA/root certificate as part of my app. In enterprise scenarios, my app users can have their own CA certificate which is not signed by any known public CA authorities. In that case, bundled CA will not help for server certification validation. If my app users have their own CA, then, they should be able to install that CA certificate into device using Safari/email. My app should validate the server certificate against this custom CA certificate.